# Get a dataframe by dataframe with duplicate colnames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I mutate following dataframe by same colnames:

```
 A.Number A.Name B.Number B.Name A.Number A.Name B.Number B.Name C.D.Age 
1      123   Test      456  Test1      789  Test2   101112  Test3     101
```

To:

```
 A.Number A.Name B.Number B.Name C.D.Age 
1      123   Test      456  Test1     NA 
2      789  Test2   101112  Test3     101
```

Edit: I got the dataframe from a list called `dataList` and if I `dput(dataList)`
I get...

```
list(list(A = list(Number = list("123"), Name = list("Test")), 
    B = list(Number = list("456"), Name = list("Test1"))), list(
    A = list(Number = list("789"), Name = list("Test2")), B = list(
        Number = list("101112"), Name = list("Test3")), C = list(
        D = list(Age = list("101")))))
```

So how can I transform to above output?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible (meaning provide code that can be pasted into R to recreate your data.frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `purrr::map_df` -

```
res <- purrr::map_df(dataList, ~as.data.frame(t(unlist(.x))))
res

#  A.Number A.Name B.Number B.Name C.D.Age
#1      123   Test      456  Test1    <NA>
#2      789  Test2   101112  Test3     101
```

Comment: So I got the dataframe from a list called `dataList` and if I `unlist(dataList)` I got

`A.Number   A.Name B.Number   B.Name 
   "123"   "Test"    "456"  "Test1" 
A.Number   A.Name B.Number   B.Name  C.D.Age 
   "789"  "Test2" "101112"  "Test3"    "101" `

... so how can I use your code for this?

Comment: Sha thanks, but `C.D.Age =101` does belog to `rownum = 2` . You can see this in the List. How can I change that in your function?

Comment: @dev123 Ok..I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

1. We could split `df` to `df1` and `df2` by column index.
2. Use `bind_rows`
3. Note `C.D.Age` is kept in both rows

```
df1 <- df[,c(1:4,9)]
df2 <- df[,5:9]

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1,df2)
```

Output:

```
  A.Number A.Name B.Number B.Name C.D.Age
1:      123   Test      456  Test1     101
2:      789  Test2   101112  Test3     101
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
lst <- list(list(A = list(Number = list("123"), Name = list("Test")), 
                 B = list(Number = list("456"), Name = list("Test1"))), list(
                   A = list(Number = list("789"), Name = list("Test2")), B = list(
                     Number = list("101112"), Name = list("Test3")), C = list(
                       D = list(Age = list("101")))))

library(dplyr)

purrr::map_df(lst, ~ .x %>% unlist %>% t %>% as.data.frame)

#>   A.Number A.Name B.Number B.Name C.D.Age
#> 1      123   Test      456  Test1    <NA>
#> 2      789  Test2   101112  Test3     101
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

These two will also do same thing.  Unfortunately `base::rbind` cannot handle missing rows so `dplyr::bind_rows` is suggested

```
do.call(bind_rows, Map(function(x) as.data.frame(t(unlist(x))), lst))

Reduce(bind_rows, Map(function(x) as.data.frame(t(unlist(x))), lst))
```